# How to define CSS fields based on props in a Svelte component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I new to Svelte and interesting to conditional styling based on props. I have two Svelte components - `Parent` and `Child`, just for understanding.

The parent passes props to child - the `pt` property which should be the `padding-top` field of child's css. The `Parent` code looks like:

```
<script>
  import Child from "./Child.svelte";
</script>

<Child pt="45px" />
```

The Child component has two styles: `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. Depending on what props are passed, the corresponding fields of styles are created. If no props is passed, then the component will have no styles. In the following example, we passed only the `pt` props which activates `padding-top` field:

```
<script>
  export let pb, pt;
  let styles = "";
  if (pt) styles += "--pt:" + pt;
  if (pb) styles += "--pb:" + pb;
</script>

<div class="child" style={styles}>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>

<style>
  .child {
    padding-top: var(--pt);
    padding-bottom: var(--pb);
  }
</style>
```

Everything works, but is this the right way? Or is there a more effective implementation of this task?
Thanks for attension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Svelte has a built-in way to pass CSS variables to a component through what's called:
[--style-props](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives---style-props)

```html
<Child --pt="45px" />
```

This sets the css value of `var(--pt)` to `45px`

Comment: (This also creates a wrapper element which can mess up layout.)

Comment: True, but https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents support is quite good 
(as long as you don't use IE11 )

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
  export let pb, pt;
</script>

<div class="child" style:padding-top={pt} style:padding-bottom={pb}>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

More info:

- [How to use Svelte's style directive](https://geoffrich.net/posts/style-directives/)
- [Svelte docs: style:property](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I try to avoid specific styling properties and use utility classes for layout.

If a component may need styles or classes, properties can be exposed with empty default `''`.

```html
<script>
    export let style = '';
    let className = '';
    export { className as class }; // Necessary because `class` is a keyword
</script>

<div class={className} {style}>
    ...
</div>
```

Then utility classes, either from something like Tailwind or self-made, can be applied for layout, e.g.:

```html
<Child class="pt32" />
```

Comment: (This disables svelte's detection to see which classes written in the <style> block are unused)

Comment: True, there are always some trade-offs 